# Работа через плагин gulp-watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, task

Когда запускаю task gulp-watch в bash , то вылетает ошибка :
Error: watching app/sass/**/*.sass: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
в чем пробема???

Comment: Ну очевидно же, что вызываться должна функция, а вы пытаетесь вызвать что-то иное.

Comment: может и так, я разобрался .

Comment: вся проблема в версии Gulp 3 или Gulp 4

Comment: но спасибо за feedback